I can start my app for testing but cannot build an apk
My application is so far Bugfree. It runs over the Run 'app' Button very good on a Hardware device and on the emulator.
I tried now to create an application with ./gradlew assembleDebug but I get this bug:

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
BUG! exception in phase 'semantic analysis' in source unit '_BuildScript_' Unsupported class file major version 67
> Unsupported class file major version 67

* Try:
> Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.
> Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
> Run with --scan to get full insights.
> Get more help at https://help.gradle.org.

BUILD FAILED in 274ms

Ive found other Bugs like this on this site but nothing of it seems to work.
This is my gradle.properties:
#Mon Oct 14 16:52:43 CEST 2024
distributionBase=GRADLE_USER_HOME
distributionPath=wrapper/dists
distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-8.7-bin.zip
zipStoreBase=GRADLE_USER_HOME
zipStorePath=wrapper/dists

This is my build.gradle:app:
plugins {
    id 'com.android.application'
    id 'org.jetbrains.kotlin.android'
    id 'com.google.dagger.hilt.android'
    id 'com.google.devtools.ksp'
}

android {
    namespace 'com.user.project'
    compileSdk 34

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.user.project"
        minSdk 28
        targetSdk 33
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"

        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
        vectorDrawables {
            useSupportLibrary true
        }
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_17
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_17
    }
    kotlinOptions {
        jvmTarget = '17'
    }
    buildFeatures {
        compose true
    }
    composeOptions {
        kotlinCompilerExtensionVersion '1.5.15'
    }
    packagingOptions {
        resources {
            excludes += '/META-INF/{AL2.0,LGPL2.1}'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation 'androidx.core:core-ktx:1.13.1'
    implementation 'androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-runtime-ktx:2.8.6'
    implementation 'androidx.activity:activity-compose:1.9.2'
    implementation "androidx.compose.ui:ui:$compose_ui_version"
    implementation "androidx.compose.ui:ui-tooling-preview:$compose_ui_version"
    implementation 'androidx.compose.material:material:1.7.3'
    implementation "com.google.dagger:hilt-android:2.44"
    implementation "com.github.bumptech.glide:compose:1.0.0-alpha.1"
    implementation "androidx.navigation:navigation-compose:2.8.2"
    implementation "androidx.hilt:hilt-navigation-compose:1.2.0"
    implementation 'androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-viewmodel-compose:2.8.6'
    implementation 'com.unboundid:unboundid-ldapsdk:6.0.7'
    implementation "androidx.compose.material:material-icons-extended:$compose_ui_version"

    implementation fileTree(dir: "libs", include: ['*.aar'])

    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.13.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.2.1'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.6.1'
    androidTestImplementation "androidx.compose.ui:ui-test-junit4:$compose_ui_version"
    debugImplementation "androidx.compose.ui:ui-tooling:$compose_ui_version"
    debugImplementation "androidx.compose.ui:ui-test-manifest:$compose_ui_version"

    ksp "com.google.dagger:hilt-android-testing:2.42"
    ksp "com.google.dagger:hilt-compiler:2.48"
}

This is the Project build.gradle:
buildscript {
    ext {
        compose_ui_version = '1.7.3'
    }
}// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.
plugins {
    id 'com.android.application' version '8.6.1' apply false
    id 'com.android.library' version '8.6.1' apply false
    id 'org.jetbrains.kotlin.android' version '1.9.25' apply false
    id 'com.google.dagger.hilt.android' version '2.48' apply false
    id 'com.google.devtools.ksp' version '1.9.25-1.0.20' apply false
}

And the settings.gradle:
pluginManagement {
    repositories {
        google()
        mavenCentral()
        gradlePluginPortal()
    }
}
dependencyResolutionManagement {
    repositoriesMode.set(RepositoriesMode.FAIL_ON_PROJECT_REPOS)
    repositories {
        google()
        mavenCentral()
    }
}
rootProject.name = "MCx Contacts"
include ':app'

I also tried to clear the project an rebuild it. I also deleted the .idea and .gradle folder in the project and the Cache folder in the gradle folder. Heck, I even deleted the ~/.gradle folder to see if it impacts anything.
Java Version is set to GRADLE_LOCAL_JAVA_HOME which is JetBrains Runtime 17.0.11 aarch84 /Applications/Android Studio.app/Contents/jbr/Contents/Home

The error indicates that your build environment is attempting to use a Java class file compiled with a version of the Java compiler that is not supported.
It could be that your project is compiled with Java 21 (major version 67) but the Gradle version that is used when you try to assembly it via the terminal doesn't support Java 21.
Best thing would be to execute the following commands in the terminal:
java -version

This command shows the Java version being used globally on your system (the default JDK installed).
./gradlew -version

This command shows the Java version (JVM parameter) being used by Gradle for building your project.
Both java -version and ./gradlew -version should show compatible JDK versions (e.g. Java 21).

java -version says Azul Zulu 23 and ./gradlew -version says: Build time:   2024-03-22 15:52:46 UTC
Revision:     650af14d7653aa949fce5e886e685efc9cf97c10
Kotlin:       1.9.22
Groovy:       3.0.17
Ant:          Apache Ant(TM) version 1.10.13 compiled on January 4 2023
JVM:          23 (Azul Systems, Inc. 23+37)
OS:           Mac OS X 15.0 aarch64
